# Is it possible to have a 128 bytes RSA public exponent?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to decrypt a friend challenge!

He gaves me a text file that contains a public key and an encrypted message.
The public key contains a modulo of 128 bytes and an exponent of 128 bytes too.

So I am wondering if this is a public key or a private key because private keys are generally composed of an exponent of the same size than modulo...

Any clue?

Comment: Sorry i've corrected the mistake in the title. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: This question would be acceptable by https://crypto.stackexchange.com by the way, if there are no dupes.

Comment: try the usual suspects that you would try as public key candidates when generating a rsa keypair ... 3,5,17,257,65537 ...